# Choose filename in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a list of urls, each associated with a unique ID. I want to use scrapy to download each of the URLs and save them in a file named after their unique ID. I went through a basic tutorial and have following code but not sure how can I get the uid while saving the file after parsing -

```
import scrapy
import json

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = json.load(open('url_info.json'))
        for entity in urls:
            url = entity['url']
            uid = entity['uid'] #  unique id
            request_object = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            request_object.meta['uid'] = uid
            yield request_object

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'quotes-unique-id.html'  #  % can I access uid here
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted. @tomáš-linhart I had tried this solution earlier but it gave me key error. that's why I edited my code above and removed the line containing exactly what you suggested. Downvotes are frustrating if reasons are not present :(

Answer (score 1):

You get the `uid` from `meta` attribute in `parse` method like this:

```
filename = 'quotes-{}.html'.format(response.meta['uid'])
```

Comment: or `f"quotes-{response.meta['uid']}"` if you are running py3.6 :)

Comment: @Granitosaurus [This](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) is really cool, didn't know that. Probably time to switch from 2.7 already... :-)